# How to use vertical-align with line-height?

Tags: html, css

I have elements from a div that goes out of their container because I use `line-height`. But the only way I found to make `vertical-align` work is by using `line-height`.

Can anyone explain me why I have that behavior and how to fix it ?

Also do anyone have advices or best practices on how to use `vertical-align` ?

Here is the code :

```
#resources {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
}

.resourceContainer {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 64px;
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/J56Ge/3/)** (Don't pay intention to images path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to reset the `line-height` for the inner `div` (because the `line-height` is inheritant):

```
.resourceContainer > div {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;     
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/J56Ge/6/)

**NOTE**: The `vertical-align` is applied to the element itself not to the child elements. So you don't need to set `vertical-align:middle` for the `.resourceContainer`, instead set it for the  direct inner `div`.

Comment: Ok, the content doesn't go out, but the `resourceContainer` content isn't vertically centered.